# Python automatically extract list index in and append data

Tags: python, list, loops, append, combinations

I don't know how to describe the problem. Given an example:

```
a=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
b=[['a','b'],['c','c']]
x=[a,b]
```

Now I want to append the elements of elements of `x` to their previous elements, (in this case `b`'s elements on every a's elements), that I can use

```
t=[]
for i in a:
    for j in b:
        t.append(i+j)
```

then  my desired result became:

```
t
[[1, 2, 'a', 'b'],
 [1, 2, 'c', 'c'],
 [3, 4, 'a', 'b'],
 [3, 4, 'c', 'c'],
 [5, 6, 'a', 'b'],
 [5, 6, 'c', 'c']]
```

In this case I know there are `a` and `b` in x, so I can append them. However, if I don't know how many items in x, how could I append the elements?

like `x=[a,b,c,d,e,...]`

Have tried with loops, but seems not good. I am thinking `combination` but not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate pairwise products and flatten them using `itertools`' `product` and `chain` functions (respectively):

```
from itertools import chain, product    
t = [list(chain.from_iterable(i)) for i in product(a, b)]
```

```
print(t)
[[1, 2, 'a', 'b'],
 [1, 2, 'c', 'c'],
 [3, 4, 'a', 'b'],
 [3, 4, 'c', 'c'],
 [5, 6, 'a', 'b'],
 [5, 6, 'c', 'c']]
```

This solution will generalise to any number of lists:

```
x = [a, b, c, ...]
t = [list(chain.from_iterable(i)) for i in product(*x)]
```

Comment: Your solution still requires me to know a and b, what if there is c, d, ,e in x as well?

Comment: @Zhonghao.KevinXie `product(*x)`, where `x = [a, b, c, ...]`

Comment: Thanks, I ll approve your answer when it is allowed.